# List and access files on owncloud public folder with R

Tags: r, curl, owncloud

I need to provide data to my students for using R in class. I uploaded the data on a public folder in owncloud. The link to the folder is public, without any password.

I can't figure out how to list all the links to each file, so that they can read it directly all of them.

So far I used:

```
r <- RCurl::getURL("https://server",verbose=FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE)
XML::getHTMLLinks(r)
```

but the result is:

```
[1] "http://enable-javascript.com/"                                         
[2] "/owncloud/index.php"                                                   
[3] "https://server"
[4] ""                                                                      
[5] ""                                                                      
[6] "https://owncloud.org"
```

i.e. only the link at the top of the page, not the links to each file in the folder.

Any help is appreciated, thanks,

A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after more digging around (e.g. [here](https://central.owncloud.org/t/how-to-create-a-folder-by-using-api/3327/7)), I found the solution. The trick is to use ownCloud's WebDAV service and specify API for public shares.

```
# Install required packages if you do not have them
# install.packages("xml2")
# install.packages("httr")


# specify your ownCloud provider
provider <- "https://owncloud.example.com" 

# specify your webDav endpoint (for publicly shared folders, do not include username)
# will most likely be "remote.php/dav" or "remote.php/webdav" 
webdav <- "remote.php/dav" 

# specify API for public links
api <- "public-files"

# specify sharing token portion of the URL
token <- "ToFnJDJKz27EQU" # just an example token

# construct URL
url <- paste(provider, webdav, api, token, sep = "/") 

# specify depth at > 1 if you want to track files in subfolders
depth <- 1

# run request
r <- httr::VERB(
    verb = "PROPFIND",
    url = url,
    httr::add_headers(depth = depth),
    httr::authenticate(token, "")
)

# parse result
x <- httr::content(r)
xml_links <- xml2::xml_find_all(x, ".//d:href")
partial_links <- xml2::xml_text(xml_links)

# get direct download links via webdav
links <- paste0(provider, partial_links)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to import files directly with

```
myfile <- read.csv2("publicowncloudlink/download")
```

since Brian brought up a valid point: your owncloud instance should have a webdav-adress. if so, check out this snippet at github:

https://gist.github.com/viking/6910f152ad0a7d3c439e2870fbcea623

it shows you all directories of the user

Comment: Are you sure this will help? What happens when you have multiple files in the "publicowncloudlink/download" folder? It seems like the OP was interested grabbing the full paths of each file that they have uploaded in the folder.

Comment: I see your point; the link in my example is assumed to be a public link to a specific file (here .csv), I assumed the final intention is to access files and not to show the dir; are you aware of a fully tailored solution?

Comment: To me it seemed like a regex job, to really select the files that they want to highlight and not all those extra ones that they are seeing when they call `getURL` and `getHTMLLinks`. One thing to note is that they asked this question in Dec 2019 and might not be interested in working with us for a solution anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find the snippet anymore. I am still looking for a solution. Within Owncloud I have a publicly shared folder with several large files. And I'd like to access them without the need to download them. And apparently is not as easy as it seems. So yes, I am still looking for a solution, although 2.5 years passed already.

Answer (score 0):

So far the best solution I could come up with is based on a bit convoluted use of the `pins` package, which in turn relies on the `data.txt` specification. The downside is that you lose the versioning capability of the `pins` package.

```
# On the teacher's machine
library(pins)


teacher_board <- board_folder("~/ownCloud/path/to/your/shared/folder", versioned = FALSE)

pin_upload_owncloud <- function(board, paths, name = NULL, title = NULL, ...) {
    pin_upload(
        board = board,
        paths = paths,
        name = name,
        title = title,
        version = FALSE
    )
    
    version <- board %>% pin_versions(name)
    version <- version$version[1]

    fs::file_move(list.files(paste0(board$path, 
                                    .Platform$file.sep, 
                                    name, 
                                    .Platform$file.sep, 
                                    version), 
                             full.names = TRUE),
                  paste0(board$path, 
                         .Platform$file.sep,
                         name, 
                         .Platform$file.sep)
                  )
    
    fs::dir_delete(paste0(board$path, 
                          .Platform$file.sep, 
                          name, 
                          .Platform$file.sep, 
                          version)
                   )
}



# list the files you want to share
shared_files <- list.files("~/path/to/files/to/be/shared", full.names = TRUE)

# upload the files to a shared pins board and specify pin name
pin_upload_owncloud(teacher_board, 
                    paths = shared_files,
                    name = "names")

# Get and share the public ownCloud shared folder link with the students
# On the students' machines

library(pins)

board_url_owncloud <- function(urls) {

urls_owncloud <- paste0(urls, "/download?path=%2F&files=/")
urls_owncloud <- gsub("//", "/", urls_owncloud)
names(urls_owncloud) <- names(urls)

board_url(urls = urls_owncloud)

}

# register new pin from the ownCloud public folder share link
student_board <- board_url_owncloud(c("names" = "https://owncloud.example.com/index.php/s/xxxxx"))

files <- student_board %>% pin_download("names")
```

You could make a simpler version of this approach by writing the names of shared files in a text file placed in the same folder and combining the sharing URL with the filenames listed in that text file.